# Ocaml code which compiles, but does not go with toplevel

Tags: load, ocaml, undefined-reference, ocaml-toplevel

I am doing an exercise of a free course. The following ocaml code compiles when I "make", but it complains once I am trying to put it into toplevel. Why?

```
let main () =
  (* Parsing arguments *)
  let f_name = ref "" in
  Arg.parse [ ] (fun s -> f_name := s) "Mini-Java analyzer";
  (* Parsing of the source file *)
  let simple_java_prog =
    if String.compare !f_name "" = 0 then failwith "no program file given";
    Localizing.current_file_name := !f_name;
    let f_desc = open_in !f_name in
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel f_desc in
    let java_prog =
      try Java_parser.program Java_lexer.token lexbuf
      with
      | e ->
          Printf.printf "Exception during parsing: %s\n"
        (Printexc.to_string e);
          failwith "Stopped" in
    Simple_java_translate.tr_java_prog java_prog in
  Printf.printf "finished...\n"

 let _ = main ()
```

But when I "c-c c-e" (from emacs) this code to toplevel, it gives me the error

```
....    
  let main () =

Error: Reference to undefined global `Localizing'
```

then, with this error information, I got an explanation from

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html

which says,

> **Reference to undefined global mod**
>       You have neglected to load in memory an implementation for a module
>   with #load.

Thus, I am trying to do: #load "localizing.cmo". But, now the problem is: There is no localizing.cmo
Here is the search result.

```
bash-3.2$ ls localizing*
localizing.cmi  localizing.cmx  localizing.ml   localizing.mli  localizing.o
```

I hesite to put makefile here, the source of the problem should not come from the "Makefile",  besides it's so big. Besides, I am not supposed to modify makefile because that's provided by the course's site.

What's the problem??  Thank you. Am I right to conclude that, Not all ocaml programs are supposed to be able to be executed at toplevel?

Comment: You can load a `cmo` or `cma`. Both can be created by `ocamlc[.opt]`.

Comment: I find the source of most problems come from a `Makefile` --mostly alcoholism.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the makefile, or at least the solution is, in part.

- `.cmi` files are compiled interfaces (compiled from `.mli`).
- `.cmo` files are bytecode compiled implementations (compiled from `.ml` with `ocamlc`).
- `.cmx` and `.o` files are native code compiled implementations (compiled from `.ml` with `ocamlopt`).

You've compiled your program to native code. But the toplevel runs bytecode. You need to compile the module to bytecode, by adding something like this to your makefile:

```
default: localizing.cmo localizing.cmx
%.cmo: %.ml
        ocamlc -c $<
```